# I'm using laravel cashier to integrate stripe. After subscription if I change the number of quantity then its adjusting price. I want to no adjustment

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, recurring-billing, product-quantity

My basic goal is to in the upcoming invoice it will directly charge quantity * price. there should not be any adjustment. How can I get it? Thanks if you have solutions

Thast what I did

```
$subscription->noProrate()->updateQuantity($quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel cashier has a `previewInvoice` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#previewing-subscription-invoices) that allows you to preview the upcoming Invoice for a Subscription given an array of prices that you want to swap, but it doesn't seem to allow for previewing quantity updates.

If you want to preview quantity updates you're better off using Stripe's API directly (see laravel's [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#stripe-sdk) on how to do this) so you get full access to the set of params that are available with Stripe's Upcoming Invoice [API](https://docs.stripe.com/api/invoices/upcoming)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I found my problem. That is created by myself

Answer (score -1):

I think the code that I put is working. I had a mass up the subscription as I created some manual subscriptions. But in real testing it look like it is working.

```
$subscription->noProrate()->updateQuantity($quantity);
```